# Discord.Net C# bot, do i need to handle rate limit when sending a DM to a lot of people?

Tags: c#, discord, bots, rate-limiting, discord.net

I made a discord bot using Discord.Net 3.8.1. There is a feature that sends a DM to all users in the guild that have a particular role every day. The number of people can reach even 2000 across different guilds that the bot will be in. Maybe even send everyone a message once every sunday.

As I was developing though, I read about rate limits.I am wondering whether Discord.Net automatically handles it when we call SendMessageAsync(like place it in a queue and execute the request with delays) or do i need to add a Task.Delay before every SendMessageAsync.
If I do need to add a delay, how much?
For example, if I need to send a DM to 2000 people, can i call SendMessageAsync every second for a total timespan of 2000 seconds?

Right now, for each guild, i get all the users. Loop through them and call SendMessageAsync without any delay.

P.S. I am totally new to API and bot development so let me know if i am missing something else here.

I haven't faced any rate limit errors as i was developing. But when i became aware of rate limits, I researched all over the place including official docs of Discord.Net and didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Does this help? https://discordnet.dev/guides/concepts/ratelimits.html

Comment: I did check this out but it only tells you how you can recieve a callback. I guess, I could try looking at the callbacks and study the rate limits myself and find some numbers. But I was hoping to get a more concrete answer. Also, i would still need to know whether Discord.Net handles this itself or do i need to implement that myself and add a delay. Or perhaps a way to find it myself. Since i am new to API's and rate limits. Don't know what kind of a ban is imposed if i start making too many requests to test.

Comment: If you do not know how discord.net handles this, you would be better off testing it. I also saw some posts on reddit to people who have tested it, but I can’t access reddit from where I am right now. I don’t think any ban is imposed, but you might get an exception or just have the request not go through.

Comment: You honestly shouldn't be sending 2000+ DMs ... this could be considered API abuse. Ideally you'd just ping/mention the role in the server and send the message.

Comment: That is what i am concerned about. I read a max 50 requests per second to be the rate limit. So i asked myself if start sending one message per second. I can send 2000 messages in about 35 minutes. I can even send 80000 messages a day and technically i will be within the mentioned limit. But obviously it felt wrong. Which is why i wanted to know what is the max rate generally(in any API) that wouldn't be considered abuse. Not just per second but per day as well.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do it, it will not proceed until the `AnyAwaitableAsync` is awaited. It automatically handles rate limit as far as i know but the execution may take longer then expected so better set an interaction runmode to async to avoid blockage of a gateway thread.